# custom attribute in magento with layered navigation as range

Tags: magento-enterprise, product-attribute, layered-navigation

How to make a custom attribute in magento to show as range in layered navigation like price any ideas please help

Comment: guys any help on this please

Answer (score 8):

So in principle what you will need to do is create your own model for the filter and then in this model create a function `_getItemsData`. This function will create all the filter items that need to be shown, in your case the different ranges. Each item should be in the following format.

```
$data[] = array(
    'label' => 'String To show for the filter',
    'value' => $fromValue . '-' . $toValue,
    'count' => 'How many items are in this range',
);
```

When you create a filter block you can attach a model for calulating it's data via `$this->_filterModelName = 'your/layer_filter_model';`

How to add new filters I am not completely sure but once that has been sorted the key is getting the data items. You can look into how the price filter works and mirror this.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion david.What i did is select type as price when creating new attribute. That worked for me a bit.

Comment: @Magesavvy welcome back to the site!  You should make your solution an answer if possible so others can more accurately see what you've done :D